# Wine: Show the "system menu" of a window?

Tags: wine

When you right-click the caption of a window in Ubuntu a menu is shown that contains commands like "minimize window", "maximize window", "move window" and so on.

Under Windows this menu is called "system menu of the window" and Windows programs may add their own "custom" commands to the menu of their own window.

Unfortunately I have a program which adds own commands to this menu and I want to run that program under Linux using Wine.

My question: Is there a possibility to access these menu commands when I run a Windows program under Wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `winecfg`, go to "Graphics", and either uncheck "Allow the window manager to decorate the windows" or check "Emulate a virtual desktop". Either way, once you've done that, close and reopen Wine, and your program will then have a Windows-style title bar, which you can right-click to get this menu.

Comment: Thanks. Unchecking "Allow the window manager to decorate the windows" does the job!